# Login redirect after authentication using interceptors in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, action, struts2-interceptors

I have a login page. Requests for login can come from multiple action classes. Once the user is validated I have to redirect it to the previous action class (from which the request to login has come). I am using interceptors for doing this. But I have missed something and it is not able to redirect properly.

**Here is my code:**

```
public class SetTargetInterceptor extends MethodFilterInterceptor implements
    Interceptor {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public String doIntercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
    Object action = invocation.getAction();
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) invocation
            .getInvocationContext().get(StrutsStatics.HTTP_REQUEST);
    if (action instanceof TargetAware) {
        TargetAware targetAwareAction = (TargetAware) action;
        if (targetAwareAction.getTarget() == null)
            targetAwareAction.setTarget(getCurrentUri(request));
    }
    return invocation.invoke();
}

private static String getCurrentUri(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String uri = request.getRequestURI();
    String[] arr = org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.split(uri, "/");
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
    if (arr != null && arr.length > 0) {
        int len = arr.length;
        uri = arr[len - 1];
    }

    String queryString = request.getQueryString();

    if (queryString != null && !queryString.equals(""))
        uri += "?" + queryString;
    return uri;

}

public void init() { /* do nothing */
}

public void destroy() { /* do nothing */
}
```

**My `struts.xml`:**

```xml
<interceptors>  
<interceptor name="setTargetInterceptor" 
class="com.markEffy.aggregator.interceptors.SetTargetInterceptor"></interceptor>

     <interceptor-stack name="newStack">
        <interceptor-ref name="setTargetInterceptor"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
      </interceptor-stack>

</interceptors>
 <action name="login" 
        class="com.markEffy.aggregator.web.LoginAction" 
        method="login">
  <result name="success"  type="redirect">
  <param name="location">${target}</param>
  <param name="parse">true</param>
   </result>
 <action name="reload" 
        class="com.markEffy.aggregator.web.PathFinderAction" 
        method="execute">
         <interceptor-ref name="newStack"/>
        <result name="success">/results.jsp</result>
  </action>
```

`PathFinderAction` can request for login. `loginAction` is used to validate the user.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a global result that will use a dynamic parameter for your target action's URL.

```xml
<global-results>
    <result name="return" type="redirect">${target}</result>
</global-results>
```

You can return this result from the interceptor or from the action that implements `TargertAware`. The `target` property should have a getter to be invoked by the result.

Comment: Sir i added the global results but it is not working properly. Target is null. I have defined an interface TargetAware. It has getTarget() and setTarget() function. The action class which implements TargetAware has this.target=target in setter and return target in getter.

Comment: It shouldn't be null if you defined a value and have a getter with the name used by the expression.